# Module pattern: return object literal vs. return object build via dot/bracket notation?

Tags: javascript

### Preface

When using the [module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) in JavaScript, is there a different between defining your module function to return an object literal:

```
var Person1 = (function(name) {

    return {
        talk: function(message) {
            console.log(name + ' said, "' + message + '".');
        }
    };

})('Steve');
```

vs. defining the function to build an object via dot notation (or bracket), and then return the object:

```
var Person2 = (function(name) {

    var self = {};

    self.talk = function(message) {
        console.log(name + ' said, "' + message + '".');
    };

    return self;

})('Bob');
```

### Questions

1. Is there a difference between the objects returned by these two definitions ? Or is just a matter of coding style preference?
2. If the only difference is style, why would you advocate for one style over the other?

While Person1 style seems more popular, my preference is for Person2 style:

- In Person1 style is cumbersome because a missed comma can break the object literal, whereas JavaScript is more forgiving about a missed semicolon.
- Person1 style has an extra level of indentation (admittedly a very moot point)

Is there something I'm not considering ?

Comment: There's no difference; do whatever you want.

Comment: There **is** a difference, it's just not exemplified by the example in the question. With the second form, you can modify the object further after the initializer, and sometimes you *have* to because you need to do something you can't do in an initializer (like this: http://pastie.org/9420120). That's just an isolated, off-the-cuff example of the general case where you need to use the object reference for something to build the object. So for those situations, you can only use the second form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's exactly the same, both create an object and then return it.

To my taste, if the object to be returned is simple, I prefer the first notation mainly because of readability reasons.